# Drop a hive table named "union"

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to drop a table names "union" but I keep getting an error.
I am not sure who and how created that table, but nothing works on it, including describe or select.
Using "hdfs dfs -ls" outside of hive, I can see that table exists and there is data in it, but cannot drop the table.
I am assuming there may be a problem because the table is called "union" and the error I get is

> "cannot recognize input near 'union'".

How can I drop the table?

Comment: try using backticks around the table name  - I'm not smart enough to show that in a comment though

Comment: @Andrew that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to escape in hive you can use bakctick:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `union`;
```